# How to initialize a container of noncopyable with initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, initializer-list, noncopyable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type)

I use gcc 4.6.1 to compile this code

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec({
            std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(0)),
            std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1)),
        });
    return 0;
}
```

In what g++ complains there is something like

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/stl_construct.h:76:7: **error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)** [with _Tp = int, _Dp = std::default_delete<int>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
```

It seems g++ still tries copy constructor in this case, though what I have put into initializer list are r-values. So how could I initialize a container of noncopyable with initializer list?

Comment: Interesting. From what I've test there don't seem to be any way to do this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't move objects out of initializer lists, since they only allow const access to their members. As such, you can't use initializer lists and move constructors; they can only be copied.

Comment: As the next-best thing, though, you could use `reserve(2)` followed by two calls to `emplace`, which won't even invoke any move constructors.

Comment: Hmm, that should be a bug of C++0x. In this situation members of initializer list should have a r-value access.