# Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, move-semantics

If I pass the following code through my GCC 4.7 snapshot, it tries to copy the `unique_ptr`s into the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    using move_only = std::unique_ptr<int>;
    std::vector<move_only> v { move_only(), move_only(), move_only() };
}
```

Obviously that cannot work because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable:

> error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr]'

Is GCC correct in trying to copy the pointers from the initializer list?

Comment: Visual Studio and clang has the same behavior

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The synopsis of `<initializer_list>` in 18.9 makes it reasonably clear that elements of an initializer list are always passed via const-reference. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any way of using move-semantic in initializer list elements in the current revision of the language.

Specifically, we have:

```
typedef const E& reference;
typedef const E& const_reference;

typedef const E* iterator;
typedef const E* const_iterator;

const E* begin() const noexcept; // first element
const E* end() const noexcept; // one past the last element
```

Comment: Consider the in<T> idiom described on cpptruths (http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2013/09/21-ways-of-passing-parameters-plus-one.html). The idea is to determine lvalue/rvalue at run-time and then call move or copy-construction. in<T> will detect rvalue/lvalue even though the standard interface provided by initializer_list is const reference.

Comment: @Sumant Doesn't seem so "idiomatic to me": isn't it, instead, pure UB? as not just the iterator but rather the underlying elements themselves might be `const`, which cannot be cast away in a well-formed program.

Answer (score 85):

**Edit:** Since @Johannes doesn't seem to want to post the best solution as an answer, I'll just do it.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main(){
  using move_only = std::unique_ptr<int>;
  move_only init[] = { move_only(), move_only(), move_only() };
  std::vector<move_only> v{std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(init)),
      std::make_move_iterator(std::end(init))};
}
```

The iterators returned by `std::make_move_iterator` will move the pointed-to element when being dereferenced.

---

**Original answer:**
We're gonna utilize a little helper type here:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct rref_wrapper
{ // CAUTION - very volatile, use with care
  explicit rref_wrapper(T&& v)
    : _val(std::move(v)) {}

  explicit operator T() const{
    return T{ std::move(_val) };
  }

private:
  T&& _val;
};

// only usable on temporaries
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
  rref_wrapper<T>
>::type rref(T&& v){
  return rref_wrapper<T>(std::move(v));
}

// lvalue reference can go away
template<class T>
void rref(T&) = delete;
```

Sadly, the straight-forward code here won't work:

```
std::vector<move_only> v{ rref(move_only()), rref(move_only()), rref(move_only()) };
```

Since the standard, for whatever reason, doesn't define a converting copy constructor like this:

```
// in class initializer_list
template<class U>
initializer_list(initializer_list<U> const& other);
```

The `initializer_list<rref_wrapper<move_only>>` created by the brace-init-list (`{...}`) won't convert to the `initializer_list<move_only>` that the `vector<move_only>` takes. So we need a two-step initialization here:

```
std::initializer_list<rref_wrapper<move_only>> il{ rref(move_only()),
                                                   rref(move_only()),
                                                   rref(move_only()) };
std::vector<move_only> v(il.begin(), il.end());
```

Comment: Ah... this is the rvalue analogue of `std::ref`, non? Maybe it should be called `std::rref`.

Comment: IIRC you need an explicitly defined copy constructor in `move_only`, because the spec says that the copy constructor is defined as deleted if the class contains an rvalue reference member. EDIT: Ah NVM, `rref_wrapper<T>` is never copied in your case so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Now, I guess this should not be left without being mentioned in a comment :) `move_only m[] = { move_only(), move_only(), move_only() }; std::vector<move_only> v(std::make_move_iterator(m), std::make_move_iterator(m + 3));`.

Comment: @Johannes: Sometimes, it's the simple solutions that just elude me. Though I gotta admit, I didn't bother with those `move_iterator`s yet.

Comment: @Johannes: Also, why isn't that an answer? :)

Comment: Is `v.reserve(init.size())` done when using `std::make_move_iterator`? Not all iterators can provide the number of elements. I came up with a similar solution that just used `vec.reserve(arr.size()); for (auto &v: arr) vec.emplace_back(std::move(v))`.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: I'd consider that a QoI issue, but I don't see why it couldn't do that. VC++'s stdlib for example tag-dispatches based on the iterator category and uses `std::distance` for forward-or-better iterators and `std::move_iterator` adapts the underlying iterator's category. Anyways, good and concise solution. Post it as an answer, maybe?

Comment: I would not have used a rvalue reference member, as you have to ensure that the reference must be consumed before the next sequence point is reached. It seems to me its not the case here, thus yielding undefined behavior. However, you could use a mutable non-reference member to get a similar behavior. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @JBJansen Not before the next 'sequence point' (a concept that doesn't exist anymore anyways), but before the end of the full expression, which is the case here.

Comment: Can "best solution" from @Johannes be improved by moving most of the remaining horribleness into a helper function?  template <typename MoveOnly, int N> std::vector<MoveOnly> VectorOfMoveOnlyFromInitializerList(std::array<MoveOnly, N> init) { return vector<MoveOnly>(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(init)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(init))); }  Then use it as:  std::vector<move_only> v = VectorOfMoveOnlyFromInitializerList<move_only,3>({{move_only(), move_only(), move_only()}});    Wish I didn't need the <move_only,3> in caller, but apparently it can't figure out the type without it.

Comment: See also my answer that uses `make_array()`. Can that be made more direct?

Comment: I wish you would come out and just say: don't use a vector, use an array (since array initializers aren't broken). Which at least addresses the case of static initializers that you'd like to not leak into your otherwise meticulously valgrindable heap. The rest of the ugliness is just lipstick on a pig.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in other answers, the behaviour of `std::initializer_list` is to hold objects by value and not allow moving out, so this is not possible. Here is one possible workaround, using a function call where the initializers are given as variadic arguments:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> u;
    int x;
    Foo(int x = 0): x(x) {}
};

template<typename V>        // recursion-ender
void multi_emplace(std::vector<V> &vec) {}

template<typename V, typename T1, typename... Types>
void multi_emplace(std::vector<V> &vec, T1&& t1, Types&&... args)
{
    vec.emplace_back( std::move(t1) );
    multi_emplace(vec, args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    multi_emplace(foos, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    multi_emplace(foos, Foo{}, Foo{});
}
```

Unfortunately `multi_emplace(foos, {});` fails as it cannot deduce the type for `{}`, so for objects to be default-constructed you have to repeat the class name. (or use `vector::resize`)

Comment: The recursive pack expansion could be replaced by the dummy array comma operator hack , to save a couple of lines of code

Answer (score 11):

*Update for C++20*:
Using Johannes Schaub's trick of `std::make_move_iterator()` with C++20's `std::to_array()`, you can use a helper function like unto `make_tuple()` etc., here called `make_vector()`:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct X {};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto make_vector( std::array<T,N>&& a )
    -> std::vector<T>
{
    return { std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(a)),
             std::make_move_iterator(std::end(a)) };
}

template<class... T>
auto make_vector( T&& ... t )
{
    return make_vector( std::to_array({ std::forward<T>(t)... }) );
}

int main()
{
    using UX = std::unique_ptr<X>;
    const auto a  = std::to_array({ UX{}, UX{}, UX{} });     // Ok
    const auto v0 = make_vector( UX{}, UX{}, UX{} );         // Ok
    //const auto v2 = std::vector< UX >{ UX{}, UX{}, UX{} }; // !! Error !!
}
```

See it live on <kbd>[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hj9osqdxK)</kbd>.

---

Similar answer for older C++:

Using Johannes Schaub's trick of `std::make_move_iterator()` with `std::experimental::make_array()`, you can use a helper function:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/array>

struct X {};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto make_vector( std::array<T,N>&& a )
    -> std::vector<T>
{
    return { std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(a)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(a)) };
}

template<class... T>
auto make_vector( T&& ... t )
    -> std::vector<typename std::common_type<T...>::type>
{
    return make_vector( std::experimental::make_array( std::forward<T>(t)... ) );
}

int main()
{
    using UX = std::unique_ptr<X>;
    const auto a  = std::experimental::make_array( UX{}, UX{}, UX{} ); // Ok
    const auto v0 = make_vector( UX{}, UX{}, UX{} );                   // Ok
    //const auto v1 = std::vector< UX >{ UX{}, UX{}, UX{} };           // !! Error !!
}
```

See it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05103a3b240cbeab)</kbd>.

Perhaps someone can leverage `std::make_array()`'s trickery to allow `make_vector()` to do its thing directly, but I did not see how (more accurately, I tried what I thought should work, failed, and moved on). In any case, the compiler should be able to inline the array to vector transformation, as Clang does with O2 on <kbd>[GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/g/6kfdeI)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I like the most.

C++17 version

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
std::vector<T> BuildVectorFromMoveOnlyObjects(Args&&... args) {
  std::vector<T> container;
  container.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
  ((container.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args))), ...);
  return container;
}


int main() {
  auto vec = BuildVectorFromMoveOnlyObjects<std::unique_ptr<int>>(
      std::make_unique<int>(10),
      std::make_unique<int>(50));
}
```

A bit uglier C++11 version

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
std::vector<T> BuildVectorFromMoveOnlyObjects(Args&&... args) {
  std::vector<T> container;

    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander{0, (void(container.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args))), 0)... };

  return container;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've [made a small library](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces) for this purpose.

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces/master/include/better_braces.hpp%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::unique_ptr%3Cint%3E%3E+foo+%3D+init%7Bnullptr,+std::make_unique%3Cint%3E(42)%7D%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+foo.at(0)+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B+//+0%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+foo.at(1)+%3C%3C+%22+-%3E+%22+%3C%3C+*foo.at(1)+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B+//+0x602000000010+-%3E+42%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.60835509138382,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-g+-fsanitize%3Dundefined,address+-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG+-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.latest%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:45.39164490861619,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <better_braces.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> foo = init{nullptr, std::make_unique<int>(42)};
    std::cout << foo.at(0) << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << foo.at(1) << " -> " << *foo.at(1) << '\n'; // 0x602000000010 -> 42
}
```

Unlike the `move_iterator` approach, this doesn't necessarily move each element. `nullptr` is emplaced directly into the vector, without constructing an intermediate `std::unique_ptr`.

This allows it to work even with non-*movable* types:

```
std::vector<std::atomic_int> bar = init{1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Wow. this is really nice.  After struggling with this all day, it's refreshing to see how simple it *could* be.  Any reason you know of that this behavior couldn't make it into standard c++ some day?

Comment: @DonHatch I don't know. `std::initializer_list` just looks poorly designed to me.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at a simple to-the-point answer for the rest of us.

You can't. It's broken.

Fortunately, array initializers aren't broken.

```
static std::unique_ptr<SerializerBase> X::x_serializers[] = { 
    std::unique_ptr<SerializerBase>{
        new Serializer<X,int>("m_int",&X::m_int)
    },
    std::unique_ptr<SerializerBase>{
        new Serializer<X,double>("m_double",&X::m_double)
    },
  nullptr, // lol. template solutions from hell possible here too.
};
```

If you then want to use that array to initialize a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, there are endless ways to do so, many of which involve baroquely unpleasant template metaprogramming, all of which can be avoided with a for loop.

Fortunately, using an array instead of a std::vector works in a lot of cases where you really would have preferred to use a std::vector.

Alternately, consider writing a `custom::static_vector<T>` class that take `T*`'s in an initializer list, and deletes them in its's destructor. Also not happy, but you need to resign yourself to the fact that `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` isn't going to work in reasonable time or with reasonable effort. You can just delete any methods that do a potential move (move and copy constructors,`T&operator[]()` &c). Or get fancy and implement rudimentary move semantics if you must (but you probably don't).

See [1] for a defense of this, provided for members of the Purist priesthood.

---

[1]   Programming languages are supposed to increase productivity.
Template meta-programming isn't doing that in this case. All I
want is a way to ensure that I don't leak memory allocated in
static initialization into the heap, thereby making it impossible
to use valgrind to verify that I'm not leaking memory.

That's an everyday use-case. And it shouldn't be difficult. Making it remotely complicated only leads to shortcuts down the road.

Answer (score -2):

As it has been pointed out, it is not possible to initialize a vector of move-only type with an initializer list. The solution originally proposed by @Johannes works fine, but I have another idea... What if we don't create a temporary array and then move elements from there into the vector, but use placement `new` to initialize this array already in place of the vector's memory block?

Here's my function to initialize a vector of `unique_ptr`'s using an argument pack:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <make_unique.h>  /// @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding

template <typename T, typename... Items>
inline std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> make_vector_of_unique(Items&&... items) {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> value_type;

    // Allocate memory for all items
    std::vector<value_type> result(sizeof...(Items));

    // Initialize the array in place of allocated memory
    new (result.data()) value_type[sizeof...(Items)] {
        make_unique<typename std::remove_reference<Items>::type>(std::forward<Items>(items))...
    };
    return result;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto testVector = make_vector_of_unique<int>(1,2,3);
    for (auto const &item : testVector) {
        std::cout << *item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a terrible idea. Placement new is not a hammer, it is a tool of fine precision. `result.data()` is not a pointer to some random memory. It is a pointer to an **object**. Think of what happens to that poor object when you placement new over it.

Comment: Additionally, the array form of placement new is not really usable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: thanks for pointing out that placement-new for arrays would not work. Now I see why that was a bad idea.