# How do I initialize a vector of unique_ptr objects?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, unique-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type)

I've tried this, but get complaints about calling `::std::unique_ptr`'s copy constructor. That doesn't seem right. :-(

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
   typedef ::std::unique_ptr<int> qint_ptr_t;
   ::std::vector<qint_ptr_t>{ {new int(5), new int(6) } };
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to initialize a `vector` of `unique_ptr` objects with an initialization list?

Comment: I don't think you can. Elements always need to be *copyable* from initializer lists.

Comment: Even if you can manage to get this to work, it won't be exception safe.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: even if you replaced each brace item with `make_unique<int>()` it wouldn't work.

Comment: I voted to close because it is an exact duplicate of that question. I'm sad. I was trying to create something that would initialize a new container by mapping the contents of an old container through the `transform` function. I wrapped `transform` up in a nice template class that inherited from `::std::initializer_list`. But the first thing I tried it on was a vector of `unique_ptr`'s because I was using the transform to do a deep copy of them. :-(

Comment: Well, not all is lost, as you can see from my answer to that question. :) Just make it a two-step process without `initializer_list`.

Comment: @Xeo: Unfortunately the real problem I'm trying to solve involves `::std::array`, so that solution won't work as `::std::array` can only do aggregate initialization.

Comment: Uhm, for `std::array`, aggregate initialization should work. In my answer, I use a normal C-style array, but `std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 3> a = {make_unique<int>(1), make_unique<int>(2), make_unique<int>(3)};` should work fine.

Comment: @Xeo: _laugh_ Interesting. I'll try it. But it still doesn't solve my problem, which is more complex. I'm trying to make a generic aggregate mapping initializer that initializes an aggregate by running all the values from a container through a mapping function. The mapping function in this case maps from a `const unique_ptr &` to a `unique_ptr`. Perhaps I will put the more complex thing in a question and ask that.