# How to make a pointer vector by a list of sub types?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a base type B and a list of its subtypes like B1, B2 which are derived from B. And I want to develop a function to make a pointer vetor with element of new B1, new B2, and or so, like

```
template<class BaseType, class... SubTypes>
vector<unique_ptr<BaseType>> makePtrVector()
{
     vector<unique_ptr<BaseType>> v;
     v.emplace_back(new SubTypes)...; // error, SubTypes has to be expanded
     return v;
}
```

I tried the above code but failed. I am not clear about expansion of parameter pack. Any way to correct it or its is just a compiler bug?

Comment: I think you can be interested [in other way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8469002/3043539) which can be used when the initialization of `vector` of non-copyable objects is needed (without `emplace_back`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do parameter pack expansion in certain contexts.  The full statement level is not one of them.

`std::vector::emplace_back` returns `void`, so we can do this:

```
struct empty {};
template<class BaseType, class... SubTypes>
vector<unique_ptr<BaseType>> makePtrVector() {
  vector<unique_ptr<BaseType>> v;
  empty unused[]= {(v.emplace_back(new SubTypes), empty{})..., empty{}}; // error
  return v;
}
```

where we create an initializer list of `empty` types that, as a side effect of their construction, call the code you like.  (`int` is also popular).

Another way to approach this is to move it into a helper function.  This, however, doesn't work on every compiler:

```
template<typename...Fs>
void do_in_order( Fs&&... fs ) {
  empty unused[]= { (void( std::forward<Fs>(fs) ), empty{})..., empty{} };
}
```

then in your code:

```
template<class BaseType, class... SubTypes>
vector<unique_ptr<BaseType>> makePtrVector() {
  vector<unique_ptr<BaseType>> v;
  do_in_order( [&]{ v.emplace_back(new SubTypes); }... );
  return v;
}
```

which looks less obtuse doesn't it?  The downside is some major compilers don't like incomplete parameter packs within lambdas that only get expanded after the end of the lambda's close brace.

Comment: I try `empty unused[]= { (void( std::forward<Fs>(fs) ), empty{})... };`. It is also fine. Is the ending `empty()` is necessary?

Comment: Hm, I got a [silly little helper](http://ideone.com/FMU30N) that makes it work... Not sufficiently different from your code, though.

Comment: @user1899021 empty set of `Ts` is then illegal.  `, empty{}` makes it legal.