# Using initializer lists with a boost::multi_index::multi_index_container of std::unique_ptr elements

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, initializer-list, boost-multi-index

I'm getting compilation errors when trying to use an initializer list to assign values into a `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container` object containing `std::unique_ptr` elements of any type.

Here's a short example (also available on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NzwFgwJJbNElof17)):

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

#include <memory>

int main()
{
    boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::unique_ptr<int>> foo;

    // Works:
    foo.insert(std::make_unique<int>(0));
    foo.insert(std::make_unique<int>(1));

    // Doesn't work:
    foo = { std::make_unique<int>(0), std::make_unique<int>(1) };
}
```

As shown above, inserting each object one at a time using `insert()` works, but I'd really rather not have to do that.

I'm using Boost 1.56.0 and compiling with Visual C++ 12.0 (Visual Studio 2013 Update 3). However, compiling with either Clang 3.4 or GCC 4.9.0 results in essentially the same errors.

Here's the output from Clang (selected for readability):

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from boost/multi_index_container.hpp:20:
boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp:153:11: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >'
  new (p) Type(t);
          ^    ~
boost/multi_index/detail/index_base.hpp:105:33: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::allocator::construct<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
      boost::detail::allocator::construct(&x->value(),v);
                                ^

boost/multi_index/detail/index_base.hpp:144:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > > >::insert_' requested here
    return insert_(v,x,lvalue_tag());
           ^

boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:728:33: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > > >::insert_' requested here
    final_node_type* res=super::insert_(v,position,x,variant);
                                ^

boost/multi_index_container.hpp:657:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, std::__1::less<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > > >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_unique_tag>::insert_<boost::multi_index::detail::lvalue_tag>' requested here
    node_type* res=super::insert_(v,position,x,variant);
                          ^

boost/multi_index_container.hpp:669:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > > >::insert_<boost::multi_index::detail::lvalue_tag>' requested here
    return insert_(v,position,detail::lvalue_tag());
           ^

boost/multi_index_container.hpp:339:30: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > > >::insert_' requested here
      hint=x.make_iterator(x.insert_(*first,hint.get_node()).first);
                             ^

test.cpp:15:6: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > > >::operator=' requested here
        foo = { std::make_unique<int>(0), std::make_unique<int>(1) };
            ^

libcxx-3.4/include/c++/v1/memory:2510:31: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >' has a user-declared move constructor
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm afraid I don't quite understand what's going on here. Why is a copy constructor being invoked? Is this just a limitation of Boost? Is there any viable workaround — specifically, one that will work with my target compiler, Visual C++ 12.0?

Answer (score 3):

An [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) only allows `const` access to its elements, which means they cannot be moved and must be copied.

From N3337, *§18.9.1/2 [support.initlist]*

> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`.

So the assignment to `foo` attempts to make copies of the `unique_ptr`, which, of course, fails.

```
foo = { std::make_unique<int>(0), std::make_unique<int>(1) };
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469002/241631) has some workarounds, but I don't think they'll be useful in this case.