# Alternate to Initializing a vector of unique pointers

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr, initializer-list

I'm in need of a way to take a ´std::unique_ptr´ returned from a function and use that in an initialization list to initialize a `std::vector` of them. I am willing to settle for any solution that involves initializing the `std::vector` with a comma separated list (ie. variadic function returning the vector) but this process needs to use move semantics to take the returned ´std::unique_ptr´ data. The issue I am having can be seen in the code below:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> create(int value) {
    return std::make_unique<int>(value);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> myVec = { create(1), create(2), create(3) }; //this results in an error
    return 0;
}
```

> Error Info: C2280 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0  737

I am using microsoft visual studios 2015 to compile the program.

Edit: as I said before I need some solution that involves simply a comma separated list of unique pointers, I can't seem to figure out how to variadic arguments that tell me the # of arguments like std::initializer_list can do. Is there some template or macro hack I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure why people keep calling it "visual studios" or why you have such an interesting indentation style, but that's by the by ;)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type

Answer (score 4):

You can't move elements out of a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Which is terrible.