# Why does std::vector enforce copy on initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

I have a copy/move probing class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Creating A" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting A" << std::endl;
    }

    A(const A &)
    {
        std::cout << "Copying A" << std::endl;
    }

    A(A &&) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Moving A" << std::endl;
    }

    A &operator=(const A &)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy-assigning A" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    A &operator=(A &&) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Move-assigning A" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And I have found that running:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int, char **)
{
    std::vector<A> v { A() };
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Creating A
Copying A
Deleting A
Deleting A
```

Why won't the initialization just move the objects? I know that `std::vector` may create [undesired copies on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows), but as you can see, adding `noexcept` did not help here (and besides, I don't think that the reasons a resize causes copies apply to initialization).

If I instead do the following:

```
std::vector<A> v;
v.push_back(A());
```

I don't get copies.

Tested with GCC 5.4 and Clang 3.8.

Comment: It's because of the `std::initializer_list` constructor being used. The semantics of that type are unfortunate.

Comment: This Q/A explains the situation and offers some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type

Comment: @StoryTeller @M.M I see, so the problem is not with `std::vector` but with `std::initializer_list`, which apparently cannot forward rvalue references? If someone can please post a proper answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You can answer your question and accept :) The SO model even encourages it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the tip. I know I can answer my own questions, but in this case I feel I'd be taking credit from those who pointed me to the answer. In any case, if no one posts an answer I'll do it myself to resolve the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't `std::vector`, but `std::initializer_list`.

`std::initializer_list` is backed by a `const` array of elements.  It does not permit non-`const` access to its data.

This blocks moving from its data.

But this is C++, so we can solve this:

```
template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T>, class...Args>
std::vector<T,A> make_vector(Args&&...args) {
  std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)> tmp = {{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
  std::vector<T,A> v{ std::make_move_iterator(tmp.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(tmp.end()) };
  return v;
}
```

now we get:

```
auto v = make_vector<A>( A() );
```

gives you 1 extra move per element:

```
Creating A
Moving A
Moving A
Deleting A
Deleting A
Deleting A
```

We can eliminate that extra instance with a careful bit of reserving and emplacing back:

```
template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T>, class...Args>
std::vector<T,A> make_vector(Args&&...args) {
  std::vector<T,A> v;
  v.reserve(sizeof...(args));
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void(
    v.emplace_back( std::forward<Args>(args) )
  ),0)...};
  return v;
}
```

[Live example of both](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb87f8232dbc0750) -- simply swap `v2::` for `v1::` to see the first one in action.

Output:

```
Creating A
Moving A
Deleting A
Deleting A
```

there could be a bit more vector overhead here, as it may be hard for the compiler to prove that `emplace_back` does not cause reallocation (even though we can prove it), so redundant checks will be compiled in most likely.  (In my opinion, we need an `emplace_back_unsafe` that is UB if there isn't enough capacity).

The loss of the extra set of `A`s is probably worth it.

Another choice:

```
template<std::size_t N, class T, class A=std::allocator<T>, class...Args>
std::vector<T,A> make_vector(std::array<T, N> elements) {
  std::vector<T,A> v{ std::make_move_iterator(elements.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(elements.end()) };
  return v;
}
```

which is used like

```
auto v = make_vector<1,A>({{ A() }});
```

where you have to specify how many elements manually.  It is as efficient as the version 2 above.