# How to initialize a vector of unique_ptr with null pointers?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, unique-ptr

I need to initialize a `vector<unique<TNode>>` with `nullptr`s. The method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type) post is too complicated. My situation is special since I only need to initialize it as `nullptr`. How can I achieve it?

I know I can use a for-loop to `push_back` a `nullptr` each time. Is there an elegant way?

BTW, `make_unqiue` does not work on my compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct TNode {
    //char ch;
    bool isWord;
    vector<unique_ptr<TNode> > children;
    TNode(): isWord(false), children(26,nullptr) {}
};

int main()
{
    TNode rt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about just `: children(26)`?

Comment: `BTW, make_unqiue does not work on my compiler.` In that case it doesn't support C++14.

Comment: @DeiDei maybe `make_unique` would work though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v (10);
```

It will create a vector of 10 `unique_ptr` objects, all of which are default initialized (not making any copies). The default initialization for `unique_ptr` points to nothing.

Note this is quite different from this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v (10, nullptr);
```

Which tries to initialize the vector with 10 copies of a `unique_ptr` that is initialized to `nullptr`, which cannot be done since `unique_ptr` can't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
struct TNode {

    Tnode(unsigned required_children) :
        children(required_children) {}
...

     vector<unique_ptr<TNode> > children;
```

From the page on the [`std::unique_ptr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) you will see that this will:

> Construct a std::unique_ptr that owns nothing.

to the number that you pass in in the constructor of your structure. So you can do:

```
TNode rt(number_I_want);
```

And you will have `number_I_want` unique pointers in your vector. They will not necessarily hold `nullptr`, but they know they hold nothing which is all you should care about.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `std::array` so you could specify the size easier.

```
#include <array>

class TNode {
 private:
  struct TNode {
    bool end_of_word = false;
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<TNode>, 26> links;
  };

  TNode root;
  // The rest of your Trie implementation
  ...
```