# Initialize a vector with unique_ptr in C++ within constructor

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, initializer-list

I am new to C++, and after having read A LOT about move semantics and unique pointers (and initializer lists), I get why this code won't work (throwing "attempting to reference a deleted function"):

```
term_array::term_array(std::unique_ptr<term>&& opd) 
    : term(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<term>> {std::move(opd)}) {...}
```

It's a constructor intended to pass a pointer `opd` (pointing to a `term` object) on from a derived class `term_array` to the base class `term`, where the `term` constructor expects a **vector** or pointers. Therefore, I tried to create a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<term>>` on the fly and fill it with the one `opd` pointer received from the `term_array` constructor. Obviously, this doesn't work since a `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, and the `initializer_list` initialization won't allow a move operation.

I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type) how to "list-initialize a vector of move-only type" in regular program flow (meaning when you can use several lines of code). But (how) can this be done within a simple constructor call? Or am I completely off-track?

Comment: Perhaps you should worry less about move semantics and unique pointers, and more about writing a useful application in C++. Have you done that yet?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I want to write a small program to evaluate arithmetic expressions. `term` is supposed to be an abstract base class for operations, holding a vector of operands (terms themselves), hence the vector of unique_ptr. The derived classes should implement the actual various behaviors of plus, minus, mult etc. Is this a bad way to approach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a helper function template:

```
template <class T>
auto SingletonVector(T&& x) {
    std::vector<std::decay_t<T>> ret;
    ret.push_back(std::forward<T>(x));
    return ret;
}
```

Then:

```
term_array::term_array(std::unique_ptr<term>&& opd) 
: term(SingletonVector(std::move(opd))) {...}
```

Comment: Still trying to figure this out... Can you please tell me why you called the function `SingletonVector`? I don't see a "singleton" (as I know it) being involved here. I also don't get why you use `std::decay_t` - isn't `x` an rvalue reference anyway, so decay should not have an effect (according to [the C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/decay))?

Comment: @Duke a singleton is a set that contains one element. `x` is a forwarding reference, so `T` may be deduced to an lvalue reference if an lvalue is passed in. `decay_t` is used to remove both the reference and any cv-qualifiers that `T` may carry.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And sorry for the stupid questions... C++ is pretty hard when coming from Java... I'm not even sure `unique_ptr` is the best pointer type for what I want to do. It all seems so clumsy...