# How to Point a base class pointer array to a derived class object on a specific index

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

How can I point pointer array of class A at index 1 to a derived class object. so when I write pointer[1].print(), it calls the print function from class B.  (its index 0 should remain pointing the the object of type A)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
protected:
string name;
public:
A()
{
name="A";
}
virtual void print()
{
cout<< name;
}
};


class B : public A
{

public:
B()
{
name="B";
}
void print()
{
cout<< name;
}
};

int main()
{
A *pointer=new A [2];
pointer[0].print(); //prints A

//now I want index 1 to be pointed to object of child class B
//so when I write pointer[1].print()
// "B" is printed. 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`A* pointer = new A[2];` reserves space for exactly two `A`s. You simply *cannot* force a `B` into this location because (usually) it requires more space.

Polymorphism generally only works via pointers or references:

```
void demo1(A a);  // accept a by value; you *can* pass a B to, but then only its
                  // A part is copied, anything belonging to B gets lost
                  // this is called object slicing
void demo2(A& a); // now can accept both A and B without losing any
                  // type information
void demo3(A* a); // alike...
```

Same applies for arrays, solely the reference option is not available:

```
A** array = new A*[2] { new A(); new B(); };
```

If you allocate via `new`, don't forget to `delete` them as well to avoid memory leaks.

You might want to prefer smart pointers to avoid explicit memory management for the created objects; a `std::vector` of smart pointers relieves you from any memory management entirely (in above example you need to `delete[] array` manually as well):

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> v;
    v.reserve(2);
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<A>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
```

Unfortunately, `std::initializer_list` constructor is not usable as `std::unique_ptr` is not copiable.

Other ways to initialise the vector are demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type), but these aren't necessarily better either.