# How can I implement the Rule of Three for Vulkan Objects?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vulkan, rule-of-three

I would like to create simple vectors of shaders, pipelines, textures, and other objects used with the Vulkan API, but I am struggling with understanding how to use copy-constructors, move-constructors, copy-assignment, and move-assignment operations.

My program builds a vector of shader structures to pass to a pipeline for creation:

```
std::vector<vk::Shader> testShaders{
    {"vertex.vert", VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT},
    {"vertex.frag", VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT}
};
vk::GraphicsPPL<triangleList> testPPL(testShaders);
```

The above method returns a validation layer error where the shader modules are `VK_NULL_HANDLE`. In another question on Stack Overflow, the solution to loading the vectors was to implement the Rule of Three, but I am now struggling with how to do so without triggering other errors. I tried a few attempts to create the copy-assignment operator and copy-constructor utilizing the [cpp-reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), but I can't seem to avoid crashing my program. Here are some of my attempts:

```
Shader(const Shader& other) // First attempt: copy constructor
{
    std::memcpy(this, other.shaderModule, sizeof(other.shaderModule));
}// exited with code -1073741819.

Shader(const Shader& other) // Second attempt
{
    vkDestroyShaderModule(GPU::device, shaderModule, nullptr);
    //delete[] shaderModule; //With or without, does not change the outcome

    std::memcpy(shaderModule, other.shaderModule, sizeof(other.shaderModule));
} // Couldn't find VkShaderModule Object 0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd and VK_NULL_HANDLE

/* Third attempt */
Shader(const Shader& other)
    : shaderStage(other.shaderStage){}

Shader& operator=(const Shader& other) // III. copy assignment
{
    if (this == &other)
        return *this;
    
    VkShaderModule new_shaderModule{};
    //sizeof(new_shaderModule) returns 8   
    //sizeof(other.shaderModule) returns 8         
    std::memcpy(new_shaderModule, other.shaderModule, sizeof(other.shaderModule));
    vkDestroyShaderModule(GPU::device, shaderModule, nullptr); // No difference with or without, neither replacing or adding "delete[] shaderModule"
    shaderModule = new_shaderModule;

    return *this;
}// VK_NULL_HANDLE error

Shader(const Shader& other) // Fourth attempt - forgot to add this one
{
    std::memcpy(this, &other, sizeof(Shader));
}
```

My shader structure is below:

```
struct Shader {
    VkShaderModule shaderModule;
    VkShaderStageFlagBits shaderStage;
    Shader(std::string const& filename, VkShaderStageFlagBits stage)
        : shaderStage(stage)
    {
        auto code = readFile(".\\shaders\\" + filename + ".spv"); // Function omitted from post for brevity, please don't hesitate to ask if needed
        createShaderModule(code, filename);
    }
    ~Shader() {
        vkDestroyShaderModule(GPU::device, shaderModule, nullptr);  
        // Delete[] shaderModule // With or without, did not change the outcome
    }
    void createShaderModule(const std::vector<char>& code, const std::string& filename) {
        VkShaderModuleCreateInfo createInfo
        { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO };
        createInfo.codeSize = code.size();
        createInfo.pCode = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(code.data());

        if (vkCreateShaderModule(GPU::device, &createInfo, nullptr, &shaderModule) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create " + filename + "!");
        }
    }
    /* My failed attempts here */
}
```

Just in case, this is how Vulkan defines the `vkCreateShaderModule` function:

```
// Provided by VK_VERSION_1_0
VkResult vkCreateShaderModule(
    VkDevice                                    device,
    const VkShaderModuleCreateInfo*             pCreateInfo,
    const VkAllocationCallbacks*                pAllocator,
    VkShaderModule*                             pShaderModule);
```

Edit:

Additions to the shader `struct` based on the recommendations from the comments:

```
Shader(const Shader& other) = delete;
Shader& operator=(const Shader& other) = delete;

Shader(Shader&& other) noexcept // move constructor
    : shaderModule(std::exchange(other.shaderModule, nullptr)), shaderStage(std::exchange(other.shaderStage, nullptr)) {}

Shader& operator=(Shader&& other) noexcept // move assignment
{
    std::swap(shaderModule, other.shaderModule);
    return *this;
}
```

and some new errors, yay...

```
Error   C2440
'=': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to '_Ty'
/* path */ \MSVC\14.37.32822\include\utility

Error (active) E0304
no instance of function template "std::construct_at" matches the argument list
/* path */ MSVC\14.37.32822\include\xmemory
```

Edit 2:

Changing the move definitions:

```
Shader(const Shader& other) = delete;
Shader& operator=(const Shader& other) = delete;

Shader(Shader&& other) noexcept // move constructor
{
    std::swap(*this, other);
    // std::exchange(*this, other); // no dice either
}

Shader& operator=(Shader&& other) noexcept // move assignment
{
    std::swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

New error:

```
Error   C2280   'vk::Shader::Shader(const vk::Shader &)'
attempting to reference a deleted function  
/* path */\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\xutility
```

I tried the `shaderModule(nullptr)` solution in addition to commenting out the two `delete` lines without a difference to the error.

Comment: Note: You pretty much never want to assign to or `memcpy` to `this`. There are valid times to do it, but this isn't one of them. Attempt 1 does a bit-by-bit copy, so you'll wind up with two objects thinking they own the same resource because the handle to the resource was copied, not the resource.

Comment: Maybe you should make `Shader` moveable only?  To mean, only implement the move constructor and move assignment operator?  Does it make logical sense to copy `Shader`'s?

Comment: That leads to a question: Do you want to copy the resource or do you need both `Shader`s to "share" the resource? If the latter, look to `std::shared_ptr`. If the former, You need to make sure you really want a copy. Perhaps disabling copies and implementing only the move operations is more in line with your requirements.

Comment: I would prefer that the resource is moved. How would I go about disabling the copies? I tried implementing both the copy and move constructors/assignment operators as defined in the Rule of Five section on the cpp-resources site, but my program would consistently use the copy operation.

Comment: @ModernEraCaveman `Shader(const Shader&)= delete;` disables the copy constructor.

Comment: `Shader(const Shader& other) = delete;` and `Shader& operator=(const Shader& other) = delete;`

Comment: Note: If the goal is to put the `Shader`s in a `vector` or other Standard Library container you will want to make the move special member functions [non-throwing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec). The Library containers won't move an object if it can throw an exception partway through the move and leave the container in an undefined state.

Comment: @user4581301 as in add noexcept to the constructor part/`createShaderModule` function? I implemented the move operations and your suggestions for deleting the copy operations, so I will update my post with those and some new errors now.

Comment: `Shader(Shader&& other) noexcept { /* move logic */ }` same again with the move-assignment. If the move hits something that normally would throw, the program will terminate instead. Sounds harsh, but it's better than debugging silent data corruption.

Comment: Side note: For now consider implementing the assignment operator via [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/4581301). It's often sub-optimal in terms of performance, but it's so simple it's nearly impossible to get wrong. Profiling the result will let you know if you need the extra oomph of a more complicated solution.

Comment: Is `VkShaderModule` something to which you can assign `nullptr`? As in, is it a pointer? It's [documented](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkShaderModule.html) as an opaque handle, so you don't really know what it is and it could just be an integer indexing a slot in a table somewhere. nd it could be something more complicated. You may need someone who actually knows the ins-and-outs of Vulkan to help you with this one. It's not something I use in my day-to-day with embedded systems.

Comment: Test the above with a stupid test like `shaderModule = nullptr;` dropped somewhere in the code. You may get a better compiler error pointing you right at that line rather than something buried in the deep-dark of the standard library.

Comment: I am no sure you have the good grasp on rule of 3. The full name is rule of 0/3/5. And focal point is destructor; I don't see any destructor in your snippet. Side note: Using `std::memcpy` is almost always bad-practice, specially if one of the arguments.

Comment: @user4581301 just updated the post, and I also tried using the test you suggested by doing `Shader(Shader&& other) noexcept : shaderModule(nullptr)` with no difference in the returned error.

Comment: If I'm right about the culprit, `shaderModule(nullptr)` shouldn't change the error message, we're still assigning `nullptr` to something that won't accept it, but the line number should. If the line number doesn't change, then I'm wrong.

Comment: Disregard my final edit. I bungled something else up that did not actually solve the problem.

Comment: Here is a simple example that is probably only a little bit wrong because I don't know what you can use as a safe "No such `VkShaderModule`" holding value:  https://godbolt.org/z/j94Pqa7s9 I used zero as the no `VkShaderModule` value for this example. It may hold. It may not.

Comment: Yeah, I think it has something to do with the way that Vulkan defines `VkShaderModule`. I copy pasted your solution and replaced the placeholders with the proper values, and still nothing. I did some testing of my own and I think it is due to `VkShaderModule` being defined using macros. I was able to make a minimally reproducible version without using any of Vulkan's libraries: [github page](https://github.com/HeyoItsMateo/Rule-of-035-Test/blob/master/Source.cpp)

Comment: I am still looking for where `VkShaderModule_T` is defined in the library, since that might shed some light on a solution.

Comment: In your example `TEST_HANDLE(foo);` expands to `typedef struct foo_T *foo;`. No one has declared a `foo_T` yet.  and because there is no definition of `foo_T` you can't `delete[] Foo;` You don't actually need to do any of that in your example. But what's really getting you is List initialization. `std::vector<rofTest> testi {{"file1.shader", test1}};` creates a `rofTest` in an `linitializer_list` and has to pass `rofTests` to the `vector` by `const` reference. Which can't be moved because they're `const`. Pain in the ass. You can't move items from an `initializer_list`.

Comment: Here are work-arounds: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8468774/4581301

Comment: Thank you for the link to that thread. For my own understanding of the constructor and assignment syntax: which is the source, and which is the destination? ie `object/*source*/(const object& destination)` or `object/*dst*/(const object& src)`?

Comment: `object/*dst*/(const object& src)`. The object being constructed will be a copy of the object passed to the constructor. Similar with the assignment operators. The object the assignment is invoked upon, the left-hand side, is made a copy of the object on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but think you are making this more difficult for yourself than it needs to be. *"I would like to create simple vectors of shaders, pipelines, textures, and other objects used with the Vulkan API"* - is the `std::vector` really necessary? Notably, the `std::vector` will move objects around in memory whenever the container is resized.

In the case of constructing a Vulkan graphics pipeline object, what you need is a vector of `vkShaderModule`, and these can be stored inside a single "Shader" object. And as soon as the pipeline is created, you are free to destroy those shader modules. (unless pipeline re-creation is a thing)

In my own Vulkan library (cannot open-source atm., unfortunately!) I use opaque pointers to represent shader objects, like following:

```cpp
// shaders.hpp
struct Shader; // opaque handle defined here
Shader* create_shader(std::string_view vert, std::string_view frag);
void destroy_shader(Shader* shader);
std::vector<vkShaderModule> get_shader_modules(Shader* shader);

// shaders.cpp
struct Shader {
    // definition here
};
Shader* create_shader(std::string_view vert, std::string_view frag) {
    auto shader = new Shader;
    // ...
    return shader;
}
void destroy_shader(Shader* shader) {
    // ...
    delete shader;
}

// main.cpp
auto shader = create_shader("vertex.vert", "vertex.frag");
if (shader == nullptr) { /* FAIL */ }
// use shader here...
destroy_shader(shader);
shader = nullptr;
```

The introduction of object-oriented programming mechanisms has a tendency of over-complicating things, like here where you are struggling with move constructors and `memcpy`, mostly because memory allocations/frees are usually placed inside constructors/destructors. In some cases this is a good pattern, but it can lead to a lot of unanswered questions.

Notably, if you now want to move the shader handle around, pass it to other functions, etc., you are only *moving a pointer*. So you can eliminate the extra complexity of remembering to pass by const ref to avoid copies, or verifying that the move/copy constructors/assignment ops are actually called correctly.

Now this may be subjective, but it seems a bit like inventing a very complicated problem in order to solve an easy problem. (except nothing in Vulkan is "easy"). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @alexpanter. It took me too long to realize that simple pointers would be the best solution, and that `std::vector`s are not necessary. I ended up implementing a solution similar to yours by using an array/pointer to pass around the shaders, where `vk::Shader shaders[] = { /*list constructor 1*/, /* list constructor 2 */, ... }`.