# C++14 How to init vector<vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>> with nullptr

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to create a vector of vectors containing null unique_ptr at runtime.

```
int display_page_count;
vector<vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>> pages_objects; // Declaration
```

my goal is to have :

```
pages_objects --- <vector> --- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- ... up to 64 time
               |
               -- <vector> --- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- ... up to 64 time
               |
               -- <vector> --- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- ... up to 64 time
               |
               -- ... up to display_page_count time
```

I tried the following declaration in my code, with display_page_count (which is not constant) to be used as top vector items count (included vectors size is constant: 64 unique_ptr which must be nullptr):

```
pages_objects(display_page_count, vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>> (64));
```

Compiler returns the following error :

> error: no match for call to ‘(std::vectorstd::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass > >) (int&, std::vectorstd::unique_ptr<MyClass >)’

The following code returns also an error due to a reallocation of unique_ptr :

```
vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>> page_objects(64); // Create a vector containing 64 null unique_ptr
pages_objects.push_back(page_objects) // !! Edited, display_page_count was wrong here
```

How can I solve this ?
Thanks a lot by advance !

Comment: The problem is that your initialization, which would otherwise be fine, need to *copy* the inner vector. And that can't be done, because `std::unique_ptr` is not copy-able. It's the same problem with the `push_back` method.

Comment: As a workaround for the `push_back` method, I think it should be possible to use `emplace_back` instead, and pass an rvalue. Either by using `std::move` (like `display_page_count.emplace_back(std::move(page_objects))`); Or by doing the vector-creation in the call itself (`display_page_count.emplace_back(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> (64))`). Might need a `reserve` call first.

Comment: Related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8468774/4165552 In your case you can do the workaround with `reserve` and then `emplace_back` or `push_back` with `move`.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not copyable. So you cant create copy of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>`, as result constructor you are trying to use can't be used. Workaround: https://godbolt.org/z/4jezPfzbs

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude and pptaszni. The use of 'pages_objects.reserve(display_page_count)' followed by 'pages_objects.emplace_back(std::move(page_objects))' do the job. I wasn't aware that std::move can be used with a vector of unique_ptr. Are all contained unique_ptr moved one by one or is there another mechanism ? 
Note that there was an error in my code example. I edited the question to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just initializing them to nullptr (default construction), why not just do the following?

```
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>> pages_objects;
    pages_objects.resize(display_page_count);
    for(auto& page_objects: pages_objects){
        page_objects.resize(64);
    }
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/E7K8TGhj5

Of course, if you can make sure `display_page_count` is defined and initialized before the `vector`, then you may just as well use `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>> pages_objects(display_page_count);` in place of the first two lines above.

Comment: Thanks @Weijun Zhou, it's the best solution for me to answer to my question, even if in my present case, the use of an array of fixed size as mentioned by tbxfreeware could be better.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to perform such `unique_ptr` initialization inside of vector's constructor because `unique_ptr` is not copyable.

The most clear way is implement some factory functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass
{
};

using Row = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>;
using Page = std::vector<Row>;

Page pageFactory(const std::size_t rowsInPage, const std::size_t cellsInRow)
{
    Page page;
    page.reserve(rowsInPage);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rowsInPage; ++i)
    {
        page.push_back(Row(cellsInRow));
    }
    return page;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Page& pages_objects)
{
    static constexpr const char* const external_gap = "               ";
    static constexpr const char* const internal_gap = "|            |";
    out << "pages_objects -";
    bool externalFirst = true;
    for (const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>& vInternal : pages_objects)
    {
        if (externalFirst)
        {
            externalFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            out << external_gap << internal_gap << std::endl;
            out << external_gap;
        }

        bool internalFirst = true;
        out << "-- <vector> -";
        for (const std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& entry : vInternal)
        {
            if (internalFirst)
            {
                internalFirst = false;
                out << "-- unique_ptr.get() -> " << entry.get() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                out << external_gap << internal_gap << std::endl;
                out << external_gap << "|            -- unique_ptr.get() -> " << entry.get() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}

void pagesTest()
{
    int display_page_count = 3;
    Page page = pageFactory(display_page_count, 5);
    std::cout << page;
}
```

Result:

```
pages_objects --- <vector> --- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               -- <vector> --- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               -- <vector> --- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
               |            |
               |            -- unique_ptr.get() -> 0
```

### Edit

Thanks to [@tbxfreeware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22193627/tbxfreeware) I've removed the `pageFactory()` function. Vector may be initialized with non-copy-able objects [[std::vector constructor (4)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)] as long as they are default constructed, not copied from *exemplary* object [[std::vector constructor (3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)]

### Edit 2

As [@tbxfreeware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22193627/tbxfreeware) mentioned, [one-loop-solution offered by @Weijun Zhou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77565055/22193627) is smarter.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Jaron. It's a nice solution well explained. The drawback is it's code size comparing to the use of 'emplace_back' as proposed in the questions comments.

Comment: How is this better than the [solution using std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566157/22193627) for the inner sub-vector, which requires no extra loops to initialize anything? And if `std::array` cannot be used, how is this better the simple [one-loop solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77565055/22193627) offerrd by @Weijun Zhou?

Comment: Can function `rowFactory` be deleted? What happens if you replace the call to `push_back` in function `pageFactory`? For example, with this: `page.push_back(Row(cellsInRow));`

Answer (score 0):

Because you know ahead of time that all of the sub-vectors have 64 elements, you can use a `std::array` to hold them. `pages_objects` is still a vector, so all the data will be stored on the heap. But now it is a *vector of arrays*, rather than a *vector of vectors*.

```cpp
    std::size_t display_page_count{ 42u };  // an arbitrary count

    std::vector<std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>, 64u>> 
        pages_objects(display_page_count);
```

That's it. No extra loops are required to initialize anything. All the `std::unique_ptr` objects are default-constructed, which initializes them to `nullptr`.

Here is a short demonstration program that allocates `pages_objects`, and then  verifies that all the `unique_ptr` objects were initialized to `nullptr`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/77564185

#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
public:
    char const* const msg{ "I'm here!" };
};

int main()
{
    std::size_t display_page_count{ 42u };  // an arbitrary count

    std::vector<std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>, 64u>>
        pages_objects(display_page_count);

    // Prove that all `unique_ptr` objects were initialized to `nullptr`.
    bool pass{ true };
    for (auto const& page : pages_objects)
        for (auto const& p : page)
            if (p != nullptr)
                pass = false;

    // Subscripting works just the same as it did before.
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < pages_objects.size(); ++i )
        for (std::size_t j{}; j < pages_objects[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            if (pages_objects[i][j] != nullptr)
                pass = false;

            pages_objects[i][j] = std::make_unique<MyClass>();
            if (pages_objects[i][j]->msg != "I'm here!")
                pass = false;
        }

    std::cout << (pass ? "Pass!\n" : "FAIL!\n");
    return pass ? 0 : 1;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
Pass!
```

##### Using `pages_objects` in a class

In response to the comment by @aga (below), I have added struct `MyPageStruct` to this answer. It shows how to initialize the vector `pages_objects` when it is the member of a class.

The first way uses base-member initialization. When done like this, there is no need to call `resize` to get the proper size. But that does not mean that you cannot use `resize` with the array solution. You can. In function `resize`, the second way demonstrates how to do that. The array method works in both cases.

In practice, of course, you will probably want to choose one or the other. You won't be using both. The code shows both, just so you can compare the two methods.

*Side thought:* It occurs to me that `MyPageStruct` would make a nice template, with `MyClass` `default_page_count`, and `page_size` all as template parameters. But I digress...

```cpp
struct MyPageStruct
{
    enum : std::size_t { default_page_count = 42u, page_size = 64u };
    using Page = std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>, page_size>;
    std::vector<Page> pages_objects;

    explicit MyPageStruct(
        std::size_t const display_page_count = default_page_count)
        : pages_objects(display_page_count)
    {
        // Base-member initialization
        // The constructor initializes `pages_objects` without the 
        // need to call `pages_objects.resize(display_page_count)`.
    }

    void resize(std::size_t const display_page_count)
    {
        // You can change the size later at any time. If you do, 
        // there is no need to run a loop to resize the individual 
        // pages. Any new `Page` that is added to the vector 
        // `pages_objects` (because the new size is larger than the 
        // old size) will automatically have all of its `unique_ptr` 
        // objects initialized to `nullptr`.

        pages_objects.resize(display_page_count);
    }
};
```

Here is the function I used to test `MyPageStruct`. It demonstrates the two ways of allocating pages.

```cpp
void test()
{
    // ps1 gets default construction.
    MyPageStruct ps1;

    // Default constructor allocates `default_page_count` pages.
    assert(MyPageStruct::default_page_count == 42u);
    assert(MyPageStruct::default_page_count == ps1.pages_objects.size());

    // Each page has `page_size` pointers.
    assert(MyPageStruct::page_size == 64u);
    assert(MyPageStruct::page_size == ps1.pages_objects[0].size());

    // ps2 is constructed using `display_page_count`.
    std::size_t const display_page_count{ 7u };
    MyPageStruct ps2(display_page_count);

    // Constructor allocates `display_page_count` pages.
    assert(display_page_count == 7u);
    assert(display_page_count == ps2.pages_objects.size());

    // Each page still has `page_size` pointers.
    assert(MyPageStruct::page_size == 64u);
    assert(MyPageStruct::page_size == ps2.pages_objects[0].size());

    // No matter how a `MyPageStruct` object is constructed, you 
    // can always call `resize` to change the number of pages. 
    ps1.resize(10u);  // Discard pages from `ps1`.
    ps2.resize(10u);  // Add pages to `ps2`.

    assert(ps1.pages_objects.size() == 10u);
    assert(ps2.pages_objects.size() == 10u);
    assert(ps2.pages_objects[9u][0u] == nullptr);  // test new pointer
}
```

All the assertions passed.

Comment: Thanks @txbfreeware You are right, in my case the use of an array could be better. Good tip !

Comment: Note that if pages_objects is defined as class member, `pages_objects.resize(display_page_count);` must be used in the code.

Comment: Not so. The array method works fine with `resize`. It also works fine without it. It works both ways. I wrote `MyPageStruct` to show how the allocations work when `pages_objects` is a member of a class (see above).