# Creating std::initializer_list from non-copyable types

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I was under the impression that, since `std::initializer_list<T>` will initialize with copying T's into storage, this would not work:

```
struct t{};
std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<t>> l{std::make_unique<t>(), std::make_unique<t>()};
```

But it does work and the above `initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<t>>` can be initialized with `std::unique_ptr<t>` which, by itself, has its copy constructor deleted.

How is the above syntax possible, while initializing a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<t>>` with a similar `std::initializer_list<>` would fail?

Comment: The `std::vector` initialization fails later. The initializer_list only hands out const references to its members, so moving is not possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller Nice comment. I removed the (totally incorrect) part about `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>` from my answer but I am now hesitant to add the explanation ... because I would just be copying your comment.

Comment: @AdrianMole - Everything here is CC. Copy away. Don't have to attribute me either, since I'm pretty sure someone already said it before :) - so I'm totally not original

Comment: thanks folks. This all make sense now. Some SO replies in other threads did not have the correct explanation of where it actually fails. It now all clicked to me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding lies in the phrase, *"will initialize with copying T's into storage"*. This is not – strictly speaking – necessarily true.

Although each element of a `std:initializer_list` is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)<sup>§</sup>, that doesn't necessarily mean it is actually copied. That is, the type, `T` doesn't actually need a **copy constructor** because a **move constructor** will be used if that is available (as it is for `std::unique_ptr<T>`) and the copy constructor is not. Note also that, when a `std::initializer_list` is copied, its underlying elements are *not* copied.

In the case where you attempt to use a `std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr>` to construct a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`, the issue is a bit trickier. That *argument* (the initializer-list) *can* be created but then, internally, the vector needs to move the elements of that list into its own container. But it can't do this, because the "underlying array" of a `std::initializer_list` is treated as an array of type `const T[]`<sup>¶</sup>, so a move constructor won't/can't work on its elements.

---

<sup>§</sup> From the linked cppreference page:

> If *other* is an rvalue expression, a move constructor will be selected by overload resolution and called during copy-initialization.
> This is still considered copy-initialization; there is no special term (e.g., move-initialization) for this case.

<sup>¶</sup> From the [std::initializer_list cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type `const T[N]`, in
> which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing
> conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the
> original initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the
> same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an
> initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the
> array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same
> exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The
> underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.

Comment: this part was confusing to me btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618268/initializing-container-of-unique-ptrs-from-initializer-list-fails-with-gcc-4-7/9618553#9618553

Comment: @Kobi If you want to use a vector of unique pointers, maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3283778/10871073).