# Why does vector take an initializer_list in its constructor instead of using a variadic template?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, initializer-list

In this code

```
vector<std::string> vec = { "long string", "exterminate" };
```

an `initializer_list` of `std::string` is created and each element in copied into `vec`. This is inefficient and makes it impossible to initialize vectors with move only types. Why can't the constructor perfectly forward the arguments?
If that was true you could do this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> vec = {
    make_unique<int>(5), make_unique<int>(55), make_unique<int>(-4)
};
```

Instead of this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.push_back(make_unique<int>(5));
vec.push_back(make_unique<int>(55));
vec.push_back(make_unique<int>(-4));
```

Furthermore, if `vector` cares about copying elements in its constructor, why are you allowed to move elements with `push_back`?

Comment: `push_back` in the shown possible constructor is not efficieint.

Comment: See the relevant question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618268/initializing-container-of-unique-ptrs-from-initializer-list-fails-with-gcc-4-7

Comment: Then you change the meaning of `vector v(0, 1)`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 That makes a lot of sense. I guess it would be too confusing to disable that constructor if you ran into those ambiguities.

Comment: You can always create a free function that helps you create unique pointers this way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the behaviour which you want to obtain is impossible using `std::vector` constructor. It can not use variadic template, because `std::vector` is a container of single type, so variadic template constructor would not be type-safe. If you really want to construct `std::vector` container with non-copyable elements, consider using the following function:

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
std::vector<T> construct(std::array<T, S>&& elems)
{
    std::vector<T> result{};
    result.reserve(elems.size());
    for (T& elem : elems)
    {
        result.push_back(std::move(elem));
    }
    return result;
}
```

You need to pass `std::array` to it in this way:

```
construct(std::array{ make_unique<int>(7), make_unique<int>(67) });
```

You can simply `push_back` non-copyable types, because they are not `const`, while they are `const` in `std::initializer_list`. For this reason, the function above is using `std::array` for this purpose, because this container allows access to its elements by non-constant reference or iterator, which allows non-constant access.

Comment: You could use type traits like std::conjunction with std::is_convertible to make the constructor type safe, no?

Comment: Yes, but variadic templates are made for passing different types to constructor. So the standard doesn't use them in single-type containers. `std::initializer_list` was specially made for this purpose, but this container has some disadvantages, for example, it can not be moved. So in this specific case `std::array` should be used.